Dll hijacking prevention in Unity project
I am developing a game using the unity engine.
I am trying to delay hacks into the game by preventing tools like melonLoader to work.
I saw that MelonLoader use proxyGen rust tool to load their proxied version.dll into the game.
I tried to secure the dll loading order following this link by modifying the main.cpp file of the generated Unity project with this one:
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    SetDllDirectory((LPCWSTR)L"");
    SetSearchPathMode(BASE_SEARCH_PATH_ENABLE_SAFE_SEARCHMODE | BASE_SEARCH_PATH_PERMANENT);
    return UnityMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nShowCmd);
}

According to the Windows documentation:

SetDllDirectory() called with an empty string should remove the working directory from the dll search path, so the proxied version.dll installed in the game folder should not be loaded.
SetSearchPathMode with BASE_SEARCH_PATH_ENABLE_SAFE_SEARCHMODE should move the working directory as th last one to be searched for dlls, so the applicaiton should load the system one first.

But it doesn't seem to prevent the proxied version.dll to be loaded.
The aim is not to prevent hacking, because knowledgeable people will still be able to edit the exe or remove the protection, it's just to prevent anybody without coding experience to hack the game, like a lock on your bike.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for your answers.

Once you've deployed binaries into the user's machine, you can't prevent them to modify your program in arbitrary ways.

Maybe (just a guess) SetDllDirectory or SetSearchPathMode are called again further down in the call stack, thus invalidating your "protection" You could use Process Monitor to check that out.

it's just to prevent anybody without coding experience People without coding experience will just download the crack made by someone with coding experience, though, that's how all software gets used by unauthorized people. Just remember that, while you're raising the bar, you can't prevent it.

Thanks for your insights. After contacting the creator of the proxy, it seems like the dll are loaded before the execution of my application, so I'll try to look in this direction.
